# C++ threads inside a 'for' loop print wrong values

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to understand multithreading in C++, but I’m stuck in this problem: if I launch threads in a *for* loop they print wrong values. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <thread>

void print_id(int id){
    printf("Hello from thread %d\n", id);
}

int main() {
    int n=5;
    std::list<std::thread> threads={};
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++ ){
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([&](){ print_id(i); }));
    }
    for(auto& t: threads){
        t.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to get printed the values 0,1,2,3,4 but I often got the same value twice. This is the output:

```
Hello from thread 2
Hello from thread 3
Hello from thread 3
Hello from thread 4
Hello from thread 5
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Pass `i` by value to lambda, `[i]`.

Comment: It's worth noting that  your use of `emplace_back` is odd: `emplace_back` takes a list of arguments and passes that on to a constructor for `std::thread`. You've passed a (rvalue) instance of `std::thread`, hence will construct a thread, then move that thread into the vector. That operation is better expressed by the more common method `push_back`. It'd be more sensible to either write `threads.emplace_back([i](){ print_id(i); });` (construct in place) or `threads.push_back(std::thread([i](){ print_id(i); }));` (construct + move) which are somewhat more idiomatic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `[&]` syntax is causing `i` to be captured *by reference*. So quite often therefore `i` will be further advanced when the thread runs than you might expect. More seriously, the behaviour of your code is *undefined* if `i` goes out of scope before a thread runs.

Capturing `i` by value - i.e. `std::thread([i](){ print_id(i); })` is the fix.

Comment: Or less used and not often advisable `std::thread([=](){ print_id(i); })`

Comment: The behavior is already undefined because this is a data race on the (non-atomic) `i` with the main thread writing and the other threads reading.

Answer (score 6):

Two problems:

1. You have no control over when the thread runs, which means the value of the variable `i` in the lambda might not be what you expect.
2. The variable `i` is local for the loop and the loop only. If the loop finishes before one or more thread runs, those threads will have an invalid reference to a variable whose lifetime have ended.

You can solve both these problems very simply by capturing the variable `i` *by value* instead of by reference. That means each thread will have a *copy* of the value, and that copy will be made uniquely for each thread.

Answer (score 5):

Another thing:

Do not wait until to have always an ordered sequence: 0, 1, 2, 3, ... because the multithreading execution mode has a specificity: **indeterminism**.

Indeterminism means that the execution of the same program, under the same conditions, gives a different result.

This is due to the fact that the OS schedules threads differently from one execution to another depending on several parameters: CPU load, priority of other processes, possible system interruptions, etc.

Your example contains only five threads, so it's simple. Try to increase the number of threads, and for example put a sleep in the processing function. You will see that the result can be different from one execution to another.