# Pthread execute unexpectedly in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to let pthreads can run their task in a specified order:

thread 1 -> thread 3 -> thread 2

When I run my code, I found the result is not fixed.
My OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Sometimes the result is (unexpectd) :

```
Before creating the threads
In thread1
In thread2
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I am thread1  generating the final report and inserting into a table 
In thread3
```

Sometimes the result is (expectd) :

```
Before creating the threads
In thread1
In thread2
In thread3
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I am thread1  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread3  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread2  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread1  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread3  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread2  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread1  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread3  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread2  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread1  generating the final report and inserting into a table
I am thread3  generating the final report and inserting into a table
```

below is my code:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond3 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock3 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int TRUE = 1;


void * threadMethod1(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread1\n");
  do{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    //Add your business logic(parallel execution codes)  here
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock1);
    printf("I am thread1  generating the final report and inserting into a table \n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond3);/* Now allow 3rd thread to process */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * threadMethod2(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread2\n");
  do
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock2);
    //Add your business logic(parallel execution codes)  here
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond2, &lock2);
    printf("I am thread2  generating the final report and inserting into a table \n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock2);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * threadMethod3(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread3\n");
  do
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock3);
    //Add your business logic(parallel execution codes)  here
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond3, &lock3);
    printf("I am thread3  generating the final report and inserting into a table \n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock3);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void my_alarm_handler(int a)
{
 TRUE = 0;//重新設定
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t tid1, tid2, tid3;
  int i = 0;

  signal( SIGALRM, my_alarm_handler );

  printf("Before creating the threads\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, threadMethod1, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread1\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, threadMethod2, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread2\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, threadMethod3, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread3\n");
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);/* Now allow first thread to process first */

  alarm(1);
  //TRUE = 0;/* Stop all the thread */


 /* this is how we join thread before exit from a system */
  printf("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
  pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid3,NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

What wrong make the result is not fixed?

thank you in advance!

Comment: You really have no control over the execution of the threads, it's up to the operating system. And as your "In thread" printing are not synchronized you could get them in any order and at any time.

Comment: You're not waiting for `thread1` to wait on the condition variable. So there is a chance that when you signal `cond1` in your main program, that signal is actually lost. You can verify this by e.g. wait a short time before  signaling `cond1`.

Comment: Nothing is wrong in your program. The execution of your threads is done in parallel and scheduled by the OS. Without an explicit synchronization mechanism in your code, the result can be different from one execution to another depending on the scheduling decided by your OS. See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093210/c-threads-inside-for-loop-print-wrong-values/60093524#60093524

Comment: But those critical sections of yours look extremely odd by the way. Why would you use a dedicated mutex/condition variable pair for each thread?

Comment: From [man 2 signal](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal): "The effects of signal() in a multithreaded process are unspecified. "

Comment: When I sleep 1 sec before `pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);` the result is expected in order.  thanks a lot. I just refer the github: https://github.com/prateekparallel/InterThreadCommunication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your condition variables incorrectly.  As [the Linux manual page for `pthread_cond_wait()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) puts it:

> When using condition variables there is always a Boolean predicate
>   involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is
>   true if the thread should proceed. Spurious wakeups from the
>   `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()` functions may occur.
>   Since the return from `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()`
>   does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the
>   predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.

That means that it is not appropriate for a thread to interpret returning from a `pthread_cond_wait()` as an indication that it should proceed.  Instead, it should interpret such a return as a sign that it should *check* some condition involving one or more shared variables to determine whether it should proceed.  If the condition is not satisfied then typically, it should wait some more.  It usually is appropriate to check the condition before waiting the first time, too, to avoid missing a signal.

Of course, all accesses to a shared variable should be performed under protection of the same mutex, at least if any of them may be writes.

On the receiving side, that all looks something like this:

```
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
_Bool should_proceed1 = 0;

void *thread1(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    while (!should_proceed1) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);

    // ...
}
```

On the signaling side, it might look like this:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    should_proceed1 = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
```

Note that the shared variable `should_proceed1` is accessed under protection of the same mutex in both places, and that this is also the mutex that the waiting thread associates with the CV for its wait.  Also, the `pthread_cond_signal()` call can happen inside the mutex-protected region, too -- you don't have to unlock the mutex first -- but although a waiting thread will wake immediately (if there are any), it will not proceed until it can reacquire the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `pthread_cond_wait` outside of a condition (usually a loop) testing some condition dependent on the state protected by the mutex is **always an error**. In the comments, dragosht noted:

> You're not waiting for thread1 to wait on the condition variable

But there's no way to "wait on a thread to wait on the condition variable". Instead, the thread must not wait on the condition variable if the condition it's waiting for has already been satisfied.

Instead you should be doing something like:

```
while (next_to_run != MY_NUMBER)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
```

and the signaling thread should be setting `next_to_run` before signaling (with the mutex held).